# Blazor upload multiple files

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor

In my controller I have the following code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadBlobs([FromBody] List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            var response = await _service.UploadFiles(files);
            return Ok(response);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllBlobs()
        {
            var response = await _service.GetUploadedBlobs();
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

In my client code which is the blazor wasm I have the following

```
@code
{
    List<IBrowserFile> files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    
    private async Task UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            
            files.Add(file);
        }

         var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/attach",files);
       
    }

    private async Task Delete(IBrowserFile bfile)
    {
         files.Remove(bfile);
    }
}
```

Its not even hitting the Httppost. The Get action works but the post action is not even hitting the controller. What am I missing?

Comment: How does the post request look like? You post files as json is that a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a controller for uploading to Azure, as it may not work correctly. Instead, use a method to call the upload from the same page. This approach is more reliable and should ensure proper functionality.

Razor page:

```html
    <div class="col-auto position-relative @(ModalDisabled? "visually-hidden":"")">
        <label class="mb-2" for="fileInput">File Explorer:</label>
        <div>
            <InputFile id="fileInput" OnChange="HandleFileChange" multiple />
            @if (UploadedFiles != null && UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                <h4>Selected Files:</h4>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var file in UploadedFiles)
                    {
                        <li>Name:@file.Name - Size: @FormatFileSize(file.Size)</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <ul>
            @if (UploadedFiles.Count() == 0)
            {
                <li class="text-danger">
                    You need to select at least one file to upload!
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
    @Code
    {
        private void HandleFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
        {
    
            UploadedFiles.Clear();
            // Get the selected files
            var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
            // Initialize the uploadedFiles list
            if (UploadedFiles == null)
                UploadedFiles = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                UploadedFiles.Add(file);
            }
            OnValidation();
        }
    
        private async Task OnUploadAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                ModalDisabled = true;
                int successes = 0;
                ModalString = $"Files are being uploaded. Please wait...";
                MessageCss = "warning";
    
                foreach (var File in UploadedFiles)
                {
                    var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(config.GetConnectionString("AzureBlobStorage"), -tYPE YOUR CONTAINER NAME-);
                    string dateTimePart = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
                    string FileName = $"{dateTimePart}_{File.Name}";
                    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{FileName}");
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await File.OpenReadStream(int.MaxValue).CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        var result = await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, overwrite: true);
                        await OnNewRecordAsync(FileName, File.Size);
                        successes += 1;
                    }
                }
                ModalString = $"{successes} files have been uploaded successfully.";
                MessageCss = "success";
            }
    
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageString = ex.Message;
                MessageCss = "danger";
                await Error.ProcessError(ex);
            }
            IsDisabled = false;
            ModalDisabled  = false;
        }
    }
```

Dont forget to inject appropriate libraries

```
@inject IConfiguration config
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@using System.IO
@using Azure.Storage.Blobs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
```

**Very Important note:**
There is a common problem you might face while using the IBrowserFile method to upload files. It works fine when you upload a single file, but when you attempt to upload multiple files, it doesn't work as expected. To avoid this issue, ensure that you don't actually hide or disable the `<InputFile>` tag; otherwise, it will result in an error. However, you can hide it visually using the visually-hidden class like this: `<div class="@(ModalDisabled ? "visually-hidden" : "")">`. This way, you can still hide it from the user while the files are uploading. You can refer to the example I provided above for better understanding.